# ¿Cómo se dice "we couldn't resist opening them until the first star"?

Tags: traducción

Estoy escribiendo mi trabajo de casa en que tengo que describir mis costumbres de la Navidad cuando era pequeña y tengo un problema con esta frase. He escrito:

> En un día de la Nochebuena los regalos eran debajo del árbol desde mañana y nunca no hemos podido resistirnos a abrirlos hasta la primera estrella.

¿Es mi traducción correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> En **el** día de Nochebuena los regalos **estaban** debajo del árbol desde **por la** mañana y nunca hemos podido resistirnos a abrirlos hasta la primera estrella.

- No es "**un** día de Nochebuena" si no "**el** día", salvo que quisieras señalar uno concreto.
- Los regalos no "eran" sino **"estaban"**, porque te refieres a su colocación. Puedes usar también "estarían".
- En lugar de "desde mañana" debe ser "desde **la** mañana" o "desde **por la** mañana". "desde mañana" tiene el sentido de "desde el día de mañana".

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, está bastante bien.

> En el día de Nochebuena los regalos estaban debajo del árbol desde la mañana y nunca hemos podido resistir abrirlos hasta la primera estrella.

Lo de la primera estrella no lo entiendo bien, supongo que quieres decir que por la noche ya los abríais.

Comment: En Polonia es un costumbre que en la Navidad los niños esperam hasta la primera estrella surge en el cielo y luego pueden abrir los regalos :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `hubimos podido`

Comment: @dockeryz, nope. It would be "nunca **pudimos** resistir" if you want to use _pretérito perfecto_, but for the "haber + participio" construction in this case, _haber_ needs to be in _presente_.

Comment: pudimos isn't pretérito perfecto though?

Answer (score 1):

> En un día de la Nochebuena

¿Ocurría todas las nochebuenas? 
→ *En nochebuena*   o 
→ *En el día de nochebuena*

> los regalos eran debajo del árbol

→ *los regalos **estaban** debajo del árbol*       o 
 → *los regalos **estaban** bajo el árbol*

> desde mañana

→ *desde **la** mañana*

(`mañana` (adverbio) = tomorrow/jutro, `la mañana` (sustantivo) = the morning/ranek)

> y nunca no

→ *y nunca*

En castellano, si ya hay un adverbio negativo delante del verbo, se omite el `no`. “Nunca pudimos” but “no pudimos nunca”.

> hemos podido resistirnos

Supongo que está bien, si sucedía hace no mucho tiempo. Variantes: 
→ *pudimos resistirnos* 
→ *podíamos resistirnos*

> a abrirlos hasta la primera estrella.

→ *a abrirlos **antes de** la primera estrella.*

Usá `hasta` si la acción o estado cubre todo el período/distancia: “abierto *hasta* las doce”, “caminé *hasta* la puerta”, “los regalos quedaban sin abrir *hasta* la primera estrella”.

Usá `antes de` si la acción ocurre en un punto determinado dentro del período/distancia: “cerré *antes de* las doce”, “me caí *antes de* [llegar a] la puerta”, “abrimos los regalos *antes de* la primera estrella”.

En este caso, se trata de una acción puntual (abrir los regalos) porque, por cercanía, la interpretación es `resistirse a {abrir los regalos antes de la primera estrella}`.

Se puede usar el sentido general de `resistir` y decir
→ *no podíamos resistir hasta la primera estrella sin abrirlos*    o 
→ *no podíamos resistir hasta la primera estrella para abrirlos.*

Todo junto:

> En el día de nochebuena los regalos estaban debajo del árbol desde la mañana, y nunca podíamos resistirnos a abrirlos antes de la primera estrella.

o

> En el día de nochebuena los regalos estaban debajo del árbol desde la mañana, y nunca podíamos resistir hasta la primera estrella sin abrirlos.

Answer (score 0):

- nunca hemos podido resistir abrirlos
- nunca nos hemos podido resistir a abrirlos
- nunca pudimos resistir abrirlos

Hay varias formas de decirlo...

Answer (score 0):

Sin más contexto, no estoy seguro de lo que quieres transmitir exactamente, así que pongo varias alternativas:

> En Nochebuena los regalos están bajo el árbol desde la mañana pero no podemos  resistirnos a abrirlos hasta que salga la primera estrella.
>
> El día de Nochebuena, los regalos ya están bajo el árbol al amanecer y nunca podemos esperar a abrirlos hasta que sale la primera estrella.
>
> En Nochebuena los regalos estaban bajo el árbol por la mañana y nunca podíamos  aguantar la tentación de abrirlos hasta que surgiera la primera estrella.
>
> En Nochebuena los regalos ya estaban bajo el árbol por la mañana pero no pudimos resistirnos a abrirlos al salir la primera estrella.

Es correcto «debajo del» pero la frase queda más fluida con  «bajo el».  Del mismo modo, puede simplificar «En el día de Nochebuena».

Si no te refieres a un día concreto, sino a lo que suele ocurrir (intemporal) puedes usar el presente. Si hablas la Nochebuena pasada, o de lo que solía ocurrir cuando eras niño (pero ya no ocurre), debes hablar en pasado.

Al hablar en pasado, es mejor emplear el indefinido «no pudimos»  o el imperfecto  «no podíamos» antes que el  «no hemos podido», a menos que sea un pasado inmediato (ayer) y/o con repercusión inmediata en el presente. La distinción parece sutil pero en un periódico del 3 de febrero de 1943 se  pondría leer «los alemanes no han podido escapar de Stalingrado» porque aún importa (y por eso *ahora* están en apuros), mientras en un libro de historia, según el contexto se escribiría «los alemanes no pudieron escapar de Stalingrado» o «los alemanes no podían escapar de Stalingrado»

No se entiende «hasta la primera estrella»  porque parece que te refieres a la distancia en el espacio a la estrella más cercana (es como decir «hasta Alfa Centauri», a muchos miles de millones de km). No es evidente que indiques una distancia en el tiempo como sería el caso de  «hasta la noche». Si pones un verbo como "salir", «surgir»,«brillar»,«lucir», etc., entonces desaparece la ambigüedad. Fíjate que siempre puedes cambiar «hasta que« por «cuando» con esos verbos, pero «cuando la primera estrella» no tiene sentido en español.